# How big is a tmp table?

Tags: mysql-5.1, temporary-tables

I've got an RDF table in MySQL 5.1 with the MyISAM engine.  Here's the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `node` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `graph` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `predicate` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `object` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nodeindex` (`graph`(20),`subject`(100),`predicate`(100),`object`(1
00)),
  KEY `ix_node_subject` (`subject`),
  KEY `ix_node_graph` (`graph`),
  KEY `ix_node_object` (`object`(255)),
  KEY `ix_node_predicate` (`predicate`),
  KEY `node_po` (`predicate`,`object`(130)),
  KEY `node_so` (`subject`,`object`(130)),
  KEY `node_sp` (`subject`,`predicate`(130)),
  FULLTEXT KEY `node_search` (`object`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=468086207 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

User-generated queries on this table construct multiple LEFT JOINs and perform full-text searches, and these queries get stuck in the `Copying to tmp table` state.

Now, Gods know I'd love advice on how to improve this, but my real question here is this: *how big* would the temporary table be? It would seem plausible that it needs to construct *n* temp tables for *n* joins, each of 80 million rows.

**Update**

I guess I wasn't clear: I'm wondering how you can estimate (or even better, compute) how big the temp tables would get. This is more a question about the implementation of a left outer join than anything.

**More Update**

Let me try to restate the question.  I've got the table above, with 80 million rows. (Actually 81 now.)  I've got a transient query, generated by a tool, that filters these 81 million rows by building a bunch of `LEFT JOIN`s and then doing a full text search on the `object` field.  To do the text search, as I understand things, it creates a temporary table, and since we're hypothetically searching the whole table that will also have 81 million rows.  So that's one.

Let's say the number of rows is *r*.

Now, consider a left join of the table on itself; this results in a new table with *r* rows. So we're got one temp table because it always builds a temp table for text searches. Does that left join now create a *second* temp table? Do successive left joins create successive copies of the temp table, to that there are *r*+1 tables created in total? Or does it "add" the new columns to the existing table?

If it's done "in place" that means the length of the row in the joined table increases by the length of one source row for each join, and thus the total storage needed is growing as O(*n*) for *n* joins.  But if it constructs a table because of the text search, then a table containing (row,row), then a table containing (row,row,row) and so forth (and now you've got an earworm for the rest of the day) then the space required grows as O(*n*<sup>2</sup>).

In other words, I'm asking does the total size of the table grow as O(*n*) for *n* joins, or O(*n*<sup>2</sup>)?

Comment: Can you show us an example query?

Comment: The behavior I'm observing in big queries is that the query hangs up everything in `Copying to tmp table` state.  If I'm understanding the documentation correctly, this means it would be an in-memory table, as if it were going to disk the state should be `Copying to tmp table on disk`. The engine is indeed MyISAM.

Comment: Dude. I can tell it's I/O bound.  O(n) or O(n^2)?

Comment: Raymond, get a grip. This isn't a question about *a* query. This is a question about how left joins are implemented.

Comment: but it depends on the query (are there derived tables or not - only left joins or inner joins as well - how the full search is used) and whether some (and which) of the indexes can be used. Table scans vs. index scans vs. index seeks have very different performance. (I do confess that I can't really answer the specific questions about how exactly temp tables are used in the execution.)

Comment: @Charlie Martin well i get frustrated when i try to help on basis on the (incomplete) information you had given.. so i analyse and try to help you and you call me "dude" (in the netherlands this is an bad definition..)..

Comment: And the math doesn't feel ok. If you have a table with `r` rows and you self-join, you get `r^2` rows (in the worst case.) If you self-join `n` times, you get `r^n` rows in the worst case (which is much worse than `n^2`).

Comment: @Charlie Martin thank you ypercube and have to agree here with ypercube.. without an query or explain statement output it impossible to say what the performance or space complexity requirement will be..  an LEFT JOIN (one LEFT JOIN) without indexes will mostly require an space complexity off an Cartesian product (O(n^2)) + overhead off MyISAM MYD header/record overhead because off the TEXT column in your real table your temporary table is stored on disk) and an Nested block algoritme (O(n^2)) to filter out the non matches so you you can better ask "how to avoid temporary tables"..

Comment: it is also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/internal-temporary-tables.html in here when MySQL is using an MEMORY engine or MyISAM engine..   you will see that because of the object (mediumtext) column and some varchar columns with utf8 encoding cant be handeld witin MEMORY engine so it will be handeld with the MyISAM engine..

Comment: No, a left join. See, eg, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join

Comment: C'mon, guys, of course it can be analyzed asymptotically. I don't care about the performance, at least for the purposes of this question. And a LEFT (OUTER) JOIN isn't Cartesian product -- it has the same number of rows as the greatest of the source tables, not a row for every pair of source table rows.

Comment: Raymond, it's like this. The question is O(n) or O(n^2), or (Gods help us) worse. Space.  Not time. I already know it's I/O bound. Any answer that includes how FAST it is, is a wrong answer. I want to know how much SPACE it takes.

Comment: @CharlieMartin you are wrong, a LEFT join of a table to itself can result up to r^2 rows (when the table has r rows). It depends on the join condition.